# how to merge two json arrays into one of this format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, merge

First Array

```
{categories":[{"label":"2018-05-24T12:04:01.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:05:03.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:08:08.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:09:10.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:11:14.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:12:15.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:13:17.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:15:21.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:16:22.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:17:24.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:17:26.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:18:28.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:19:30.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:20:31.000Z"},{"label":"2018-05-24T12:21:33.000Z"}]}
```

second Array

```
{data":[{"value":23.44},{"value":23.43},{"value":23.42},{"value":23.4},{"value":23.4},{"value":23.38},{"value":23.37},{"value":23.36},{"value":23.35},{"value":23.38},{"value":23.4},{"value":23.4},{"value":23.38},{"value":23.39},{"value":23.37},{"value":23.35},{"value":23.34},{"value":23.35},{"value":23.34},{"value":23.32},{"value":23.35},{"value":23.35},{"value":23.35},{"value":23.35},{"value":23.35},{"value":23.37},{"value":23.3},{"value":23.35},{"value":23.35},{"value":23.32},{"value":23.34},{"value":23.33},{"value":23.35},{"value":23.32},{"value":23.34},{"value":23.35},{"value":23.32},{"value":23.34},{"value":23.35}]}
```

Resulting Array :

```
[[2018-05-24T12:04:01.000Z , 23.44 ] , [2018-05-24T12:05:03.000Z , 23.43],.....]
```

Comment: One is that you loop through both but I don't see any attempt or difficulty, so I failed to identify your issue, other then actually doing it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5734311)

Comment: i don't know how to make 2d array from two 1d array !

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = categories.map(({label}, index) => ([label, data[index].value]));
```

Loop through the categories and add the data at the same position.

Comment: i don't know how to make 2d array from two 1d array !